# Sql Dates to Columns for Timecard (dynamic)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Name   Date                           Duration
------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
Leiuck 02/23/2014                     12.50
Annver 02/24/2014                     8.00
Leiuck 02/24/2014                     9.00
Mauler 02/24/2014                     8.00
Shaman 02/24/2014                     4.00
Annver 02/25/2014                     8.00
Leiuck 02/25/2014                     8.50
Mauler 02/25/2014                     8.00
Shaman 02/25/2014                     6.00
Annver 02/26/2014                     8.00
Leiuck 02/26/2014                     8.50
Shaman 02/26/2014                     7.00
Annver 02/27/2014                     8.00
Shaman 02/27/2014                     6.00
```

I need the dates to be the columns and the duration to be the result.

```
select
    Name = left( per.Name, 3) + right( per.Name, 3)
,   Date = convert( varchar, t.EntryDate, 101)
,   Duration = sum(t.Duration)
from tentry t (nolock)
left join tpers per (nolock) on t.PersonID = per.PersonID
where
    t.EntryDate >= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) -0, -1)
and t.EntryDate <= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) -0,  5)
and per.Division = 1
and per.Act = 1
group by
    per.Name
,   t.EntryDate
```

Please help.

More info...

I need the output to look something like this.  Thank you so much for trying to help me out.

```
Name    2/23/2014   2/24/2014   2/25/2014   2/26/2014   2/27/2014
Annver              8           8           8           8
Leiuck  12.5        9           8.5         8.5         
Mauler              8           8                       
Shaman              4           6           7           6
```

Comment: What type is the Duration column in your table?

Comment: the hours spent on the day.  An int.

Comment: Sounds like sorcery... or a `PIVOT` query.

Comment: +1 for providing sample data, desired output and your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME([Date]) 
                      FROM TableName 
                      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).
                      value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2,'')
FROM TableName t


SET @Sql = N'SELECT *
             FROM TableName t
             PIVOT (SUM(Duration)
                    FOR [Date]
                    IN ('+ @Cols +')
                    )p'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║  Name  ║ 2014-02-23 ║ 2014-02-24 ║ 2014-02-25 ║ 2014-02-26 ║ 2014-02-27 ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Annver ║ NULL       ║ 8.00       ║ 8.00       ║ 8.00       ║ 8.00       ║
║ Leiuck ║ 12.50      ║ 9.00       ║ 8.50       ║ 8.50       ║ NULL       ║
║ Mauler ║ NULL       ║ 8.00       ║ 8.00       ║ NULL       ║ NULL       ║
║ Shaman ║ NULL       ║ 4.00       ║ 6.00       ║ 7.00       ║ 6.00       ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

### [`WORKING SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2059a/3)

Comment: Good answer... thought I'd contribute by removing the nulls... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2059a/29  hope it's okay.

Comment: This is great!  I know that I didn't ask for this originally but is there a way to add in the dates that don't have data?  You can see the date range in my original request.

Comment: To add dates that don't exist you need to get them into your list of columns used in the pivot query, you can do that by appending them manually, or you can create a driver table/cte that has all the dates you are interested in to use instead of pulling the dates from your table.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(1000),
        @query  AS VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +   QUOTENAME([date]) 
                    FROM Table1
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    ,1,1,'')

SET @query = '
              SELECT * 
              FROM  Table1 
              PIVOT (max(Duration) for [Date] in ('+@cols+')) p
            '
EXEC (@query)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80ad1/5/0)